# Using data-src isn't rendering an image in ember.js 2

Tags: html, ember.js

I am using Ember.js andI am having an issue getting this piece of code to render out a logo.

`<span data-src="/images/logo.png"></span>`

Does Ember.js not allow the use of data-src? I have gone through the docs and I havent seen anything that alludes to this.

Comment: Have you tried `./images/logo.png`? or any other variation thereof? Also, have you verified you don't need to navigate up any folders(ie verifying that you're pointing to where you think you're pointing to)?

Comment: This isn't angular

Answer (score 2):

Why would the span render an image? Is it a custom component that handles the span and converts into an img tag?

How about using an img tag?

```
<img src={{logoUrl}} alt="Logo">
```

One important thing with ember-cli and images is that you have to 
create folder inside public -> public/assets/images/, and place your images inside. You can then access them in the browser using /assets/images/logo.png

They will be then properly imported after precompiling for production

Hope it helps